# jQuery .click() on an item inside a carousel

Tags: jquery, model, dialog, click, carousel

I have an item inside a carousel and tied .click() event binding to it. And it is working all great, because that item is in the first page of carousel and visible right on load.

But if I move the carousel so that it becomes invisible and then move back in the viewport, the click() event isn't working anymore?

I probably just have to register it somehow again when it is visible?

BTW Click is used to open a modal jQuery UI dialog

Thanks

Comment: How can we help you find bugs in code we don't see ? Post the code in your question and/or create a [jsfiddle](http://www..jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://www.elveneleven.com/WhyGo/

Sorry, I thought it might be just a matter of "re-register the click event on carousel being moved" or something general advice like that would be nice... Although the exact code would be cool as well ;)

Comment: Are you talking about the dialog that opens when you click on "Get a quick quote" ? Works for me all the time, whatever I do (take the tour, play with the accordion...)

Comment: That's fine, but it doesn't work for me if I play with the bottom carousel. If it goes out of the viewport in the carousel and you move it back in it isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following you comment, I noticed indeed that the click was not working anymore when you looped through the carousel.

I don't know exactly how this plugin works. I suppose it may re-creates the elements and the event handler is lost in the way.

An approach to resolve this is to use event delegation.
Basically you will delegate the execution of the click on `.quickQoute` to the a container, in your case the carousel element `#inner`:

```
$('#inner').on('click', '.quickQoute', function () {
    $("#quickQoute").dialog({ closeText: ' ' });
    $("#quickQoute").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

More on event delegation with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: This is just brilliant! I love learning new things every day. Elegant, explanatory and useful. Great job and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [liveQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

This will automatically bind events to elements when they are created. For example:

```
$(".some_appearing_button").livequery('click',function () {

        alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

This allows you to set event handlers first, and have the option to have elements created at a later time, like your carrousel does.

Comment: livequery is absolutely not relevant anymore: jQuery implements *natively* event delegation since 1.3...

Comment: livequery is an entirely different concept from .live(), if that's what you mean. Else, please elaborate :)

Comment: Didier, I get that bindig it to a click event can be changed to the delegate/on qfunctionality, but there are some things those functions still can't do. For example, in an application i made, I added 'datepicker' class to textboxes that needed a atepicker. Livequery was triggerend on this class, and it automatically cleaned up the textbox input. I couldn't get that to work with on/delegate because those work with events, but there is no 'item_is_created' event. Hence livequery. It still has good usages in those scenarios.

Comment: My comment was related to the question actually. In the case you explain I understand it is useful as event delegation works for events only. In the current context though, I think it's best to rely on jquery's .on() or .delegate() than on an external plugin.